# Angular controllers: 1 per view - does it make sense?

Tags: angularjs

I have been thinking about this lately. Up until now I have always subscribed to John Papa's recommendation which can be seen here:

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#controllers

```
Define a controller for a view, and try not to reuse the controller for other views. Instead, move reusable logic to factories and keep the controller simple and focused on its view.
```

He gives a reason that I don't understand but for me it was primarily motivated by ease-of-work/maintainability. Basically, in working on large applications, it really sucks to come upon a bloated controller that is responsible for several disparate views. If a developer wants to clean up the controller, he/she has to go to each view and determine what is being used and why (so that methods can be consolidated if they are very similar) which is a big job. Typically (especially if they are under time constraints), they choose to just add  whatever functionality they need to the model and to "come back to it later" which is how it got bloated in the first place. Also, I have always used the controller/directive as an indication of whether logic is repeated in many views or not (i.e. if another developer walks up to a controller that I have written he/she can be sure that I have only used it with one view because otherwise it would be directive).

This is a similar problem to the endpoint-problem which basically has people adding endpoints on an as-need basis and the eventually due to new people not knowing about old endpoints or simple forgetfulness the API gets super bloated and repetitive.

However, as I said, recently I have been thinking that this 1-1 controller to view relationship really works against the entire MVC pattern because it couples the model to the view and destroys the separation of concerns. I mean, as long as a controller stays focused (i.e. we have an EditUserCtrl whose job it is to edit a user etc.) then why shouldn't two views be able to use that controller? I mean if the business decides it needs a new view in another place that has the same function, why shouldn't I just write a new view and hook it up to the old controller? I guess what I am saying is that I am having trouble reconciling a convention that goes against the fundamentals of a framework.

Would love to hear others thoughts on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said yourself. If a controller is responsible for more than one view, any developer can walk up to it, change something in the hopes of adding new functionality to **view A** and not even knowing it's breaking **view B**. I think the primarily goal would be to keep controllers clean and neat. That way, it's best to have 2 controllers almost identicals, but with only 2~3 line of codes than to have files being referenced by a numerous number of other files that nobody has control over it.

At one hand, you have to change 2 controllers if something drastically changes in **view A** and **view B**, but if it's a complex task, you'll probably have the controllers calling some sort of **Gateway** and that might mean that you won't have to change any of the controllers at all (good outcome).
On the other hand, if you have 10 different views repeating the same 2~3 lines of code, maybe it's time to abstract the controller functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't couple the model because the it's best practice to have the business logic in services and view logic in directives , and have there be no real logic in the controllers. So you can one controller per view, but that controller should be very skinny. Personally, I like to only use controllers to assign and communicate variables between services and directives. If you want to reuse controller code, what's stopping you from either putting that logic in directives and services?

Almost none of the controllers I write (and for my job I write a large enterprise application in angular) have logic in them. Granted sometimes logic in controllers is unavoidable, but try to keep as little as possible there.

In this way, the controller stays focused. For a large application, with, say, 10 pages, it's better for both usability and readability to have small controllers for each page instead of one giant controller with a mix of variables, and when you want to re-use methods and functions, put them in services. If you find yourself having three pages with a form or button that has the exact same logic, then that might be better served with a custom directive.